# Give permission to all my application development team in my gcp storage through my webportal

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am about to purchase a GCP Storage but having trouble in giving access to all developers in the project as there are lots of people working on a project (this varies), that's why I cant add each and every personal detail through the GCP portal, I have my company's portal from where I used to manage developers and there project,
`so my question is, can I do something to add developers directly to my storage with all permissions through my project management web portal? is there any API or something??`

Comment: Your question does not have details on what your "project management web portal" is, 
 or how it provides authentication and authorization. Google Cloud supports OAuth and SAML federation. Edit your question with details, links to show the research that you have completed and the problem you have. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways through which you can provide access to your Cloud Storage to your developers.

- Create a [Service account](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts) and provide the required permissions to the service account and share the service account key to your developers. Remember to provide minimum privileges to your service account and share the key securely as anyone with access to the key will have access to GCP until you revoke the key or delete the service account.
- Create a Google Group and add your dev team members to that group and provide permissions to the Google Group in GCP. Your team members will automatically get the permissions if they are part of the group.

You can also use [Cloud Storage API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/apis) to programmatically manage permissions to your buckets.